# Set value for a html label from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm not sure Is this possible ?
but, I have a label in html page.

```
<label name='example'>Page 1</label>
```

I want to update the label value to something else after i get to another page from my controller `servlet`:

```
<label name='example'>Page 2 (update being update from servlet)</label>
```

Can anyone understand my question and help?

Comment: @can you post your code which you have tried so far

Comment: if you have two different pages, why don't you use different labels on each page?

Comment: If your problem is preserving state accross multiple request, you need to use once of avilable persistence mechanism (eg: Session, Cookie, database, etc)

Comment: @Saurabh because i use jsp to include the template in..if i manual change the label value i have to copy and paste the whole thing.

Comment: @Bhushan i havent try any code...becuz i dont know if its even possible to do it or not..=[..i mean in asp.net u can update label so i thought jsp u can too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly update it as a servlet from Page 2 can only write response to Page 2 .

However you can use session to share/update data between pages , update the session variable in page 2 and auto-refresh the page one every few second to reflect that change.

If you were opening a child window however then you can use the JavaScript on child window to update the items on Parent page.